# Exercício trocando ultimo elemento

Tags: python

exercício:

> Escreva uma função que recebe uma frase e uma palavra antiga e uma
>   palavra nova. A função deve retornar uma string contendo a frase
>   original, mas com a última ocorrência da palavra antiga substituída
>   pela palavra nova. A entrada e saída de dados deve ser feita no
>   programa principal

Fiz da seguinte forma:

```
frase=input('digite uma frase:')
palavraAntiga = input('digite uma palavra da frase:')
palavraNova = input('digite uma palavra nova pra substitui-la:')
restante = frase.rsplit(palavraAntiga, 1)
frase = palavraNova.join(restante)
print(frase)
```

De certa forma desse jeito que fiz dar certo porem fazendo o seguinte teste ele nao sai do jeito que eu quero. Teste:

```
digite uma frase:a a b b a c b d aa
digite uma palavra da frase:a
digite uma palavra nova pra substitui-la:KKK
a a b b a c b d aKKK
```

Gostaria de saber como faço para que a palavra **aa** nao seja substituida e sim apenas a palavra **a** para que fique assim:

```
a a b b KKK c b d aa
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olá, você pode separar a *string* original nos espaços.

Ex.

```
alphabet = "a b c d e f g ee"
old = "e"
new = "kk"
last = -1;
data = alphabet.split()
```

E depois é só percorrer a lista resultante comparando a *string* com a nova que será trocada.

```
for index, temp in enumerate(data):
    if temp == old:
        last = index
```

Dessa forma você pode ir armazenando as posições em uma variável(sobrescrevendo) e no final você terá o valor da última posição da ocorrência ai é só trocar.

```
if last != -1:
    data[last] = new
```

> É interessante verificar se existe ao menos uma ocorrência.

Depois é só unir novamente com `alphabet = " ".join(data)` e exibir `print alphabet`.

> **NOTA**: Observe a versão do python que está utilizando e faça as correções para ela

Answer (score 2):

Apenas para complemento e ver outras soluções ao problema, também consegue resolver através de uma expressão regular não muito elaborada.

Imaginando que tem a palavra antiga `a` a substituir por `KKK` a regex seria:

```
\b(a)\b(?!.*\b\1\b)
```

Explicação:

```
\b  - Inicio de palavra
(a) - Captura da palavra "a"
\b  - Fim de palavra
(?! - Negative lookahead - Que não tenha à frente
.*  - Qualquer coisa
\b  - Seguida de inicio de palavra
\1  - Com a mesma captura feita antes
\b  - E fim de palavra
```

Lendo em português, seria algo como: Capturar a palavra `"a"` que não tenha à frente outra palavra `"a"`.

[Veja no regex101](https://regex101.com/r/I46ea0/1)

Em código Python:

```
import re
frase=input('digite uma frase:')
palavraAntiga = input('digite uma palavra da frase:')
palavraNova = input('digite uma palavra nova pra substitui-la:')
novaFrase = re.sub(r"\b(" + palavraAntiga + r")\b(?!.*\b\1\b)", palavraNova, frase) # aplicar regex
print(novaFrase)
```

[Veja a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/20OH6z)

A aplicação da regex foi feita com o `re.sub` que recebe os seguintes parametros:

1. Expressão regular
2. A substituição
3. A string onde se vai fazer a substituição

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o método [`str.rpartition`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.rpartition) que irá dividir a *string* na última ocorrência do separador, retornando uma tupla de 3 valores: a parte da *string* antes da divisão, o próprio separador e a parte após a divisão. Para substituir pela nova palavra, basta unir as duas partes com a nova.

```
>>> frase = "da forma que fiz funciona, que coisa, não?"
>>> before, separator, after = frase.rpartition('que')
>>> nova_frase = f'{before}QUE{after}'
>>> print(nova_frase)
da forma que fiz funciona, QUE coisa, não?
```

Mas somente desta forma ele não substituiria apenas a palavra, mas sim a última ocorrência dela na *string*. A frase `piquenique` viraria `piqueniQUE`, mesmo não possuindo a palavra substituída `que`. Para tal, demandará algumas condições extras de validação que deixo a seu critério elaborá-las.